# In MySQL if column A and column B not have the same value fetch the data

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query to fetch recently login customers but I'm not sure why I get no results!

> lastActivity date is stored in customer table as well as in
>   customer_statistics lastActivity

Here is my query:

```
mysql> SELECT `customer`.`lastActivity`, `customer_statistics`.`lastActivity`,  `customer`.`lastActivity` = customer_statistics.lastActivity as todate
FROM (`customer`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `customer_statistics` ON `customer`.`id` = `customer_statistics`.`customer`
WHERE `customer`.`lastActivity` = `customer_statistics`.`lastActivity` IN ('0', 'NULL')
```

Here is how the data looks like (before where in), and from this list I just need row 1 and 2.

```
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
| id | date 1     | date 2     | todate      |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | 2017-02-12 | 2017-02-13 | 0           |
|  2 | 2017-02-13 | NULL       | NULL        |
|  3 | 2017-02-15 | 2017-02-15 | 1           |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT null IN (null) from DUAL;` returns `null`. Instead, you need:

```
SELECT `customer`.`lastActivity`, `customer_statistics`.`lastActivity`,  `customer`.`lastActivity` = customer_statistics.lastActivity as todate
FROM (`customer`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `customer_statistics` ON `customer`.`id` = `customer_statistics`.`customer`
WHERE `customer`.`lastActivity` != `customer_statistics`.`lastActivity` OR `customer`.`lastActivity` IS NULL OR `customer_statistics`.`lastActivity` IS NULL
```